# Python syntax error in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Professor introduced a new way to write some code.

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y=[i<6 , for i in x]
print(y)
```

I am expecting the following output

```
True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False
```

Is there a syntax error in the y statement? My program is highlight the for part.

Comment: you shouldn't have a comma: `y=[i<6 for i in x]`

Answer (score 3):

You don't use `,` in a list comprehension. This works fine:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

y = [i<6 for i in x]

print(y)
```

Returns `[True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False]`

What your professor is teaching you is [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). I love them. Succinct to write.

Alternatively, you could have written it like this, which is way longer:

```
z = []

for i in x:
    if i < 6:
        z.append(True)
    else:
        z.append(False)

print(z)
```

Would return `[True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False]`

By the way, the above code can **also** be written with shorthand if else syntax:

```
    z = []
    for i in x:
        z.append(True) if i < 6 else z.append(False)
    return z
```

Anyway, here is a more full solution with unit testing for your perusal.

```
import unittest

def so_26923986(x):

    y = [i < 6 for i in x]
    return y 

def so_26923986_1(x):

    z = []
    for i in x:
        z.append(True) if i < 6 else z.append(False)
    return z
```

**Unit Test**

```
# Unit Test
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def testcase(self):
        self.assertEqual(so_26923986([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), [True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False])
        self.assertEqual(so_26923986_1([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), [True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False])

        self.assertEqual(so_26923986([1, 2, 3]), [True, True, True])
        self.assertEqual(so_26923986_1([1, 2, 3]), [True, True, True])

        self.assertEqual(so_26923986([1, 2, 7, 10, 3, 8]), [True, True, False, False, True, False])
        self.assertEqual(so_26923986_1([1, 2, 7, 10, 3, 8]), [True, True, False, False, True, False])

unittest.main()
```

**Test Passing**

```
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write like :

```
    x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    y=[i<6 for i in x]
    print y
```

Your code is fine but remove `,` from list.

output :

```
   [True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False]
```